# To put a plot inside of a plot

Tags: plotting, image, graphics

I'd like to put a figure of a 2D-plot into a larger 2D-plot (into some white-space), like in the example below:

[image: The plot inside plot example]

I don't precesely know how It's done, could anyone help me with this one? Is it with the command Epilog somehow ?

Comment: Thanks, my search wasn't thorough enough I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html):

```
Plot[Exp[-x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> Inset[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}], Scaled[{.7, .5}]]]
```

[image: inset plot in plot]